# Complementary exercises to YOGA for releasing tension?

Tags: yoga, foam-rolling

What exercises and exercise systems are the best complementary exercises to Yoga for releasing tension (immediate effect)

I am thinking of non-strenuous exercises like foam rolling.

With Yoga I mean Asana Yoga as in Hata, Ingyear or Bikram.

My current Yoga practice are Asanas on the floor, sometimes with a belt, sometimes rolling over a roll on my back (facing up)

Comment: I'm confused: Isn't Yoga supposed to release tension?  If yoga isn't doing this for you, then maybe you should stop doing it.  Maybe try Tai Chi?

Answer (score 1):

Pranayam (in Hata yoga) is the best yoga practice for releasing tension and stress level.
There are many types of pranayam. It is relevant to breathing concentration exercise.

1) 'Anulom-Vilom' Pranayam

2) 'Nadishudhhi' Pranayam

3) 'Ujjayi' Pranayam

'Kapalbhati' is also the good breathing exercise. Initially, You can do 5 rounds daily and later you can increase the rounds.

Answer (score 1):

Savasana is the best complement, and can be performed at the end of every yoga session. Along with that meditation or anything that boosts awareness throughout helps best releasing tension.